# Passing a FormGroup to a component for using ng-container for validation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, formgroups

I am learning angular. And i want to extract my form html code for that i can reuse it later.
The visualization is working. But i have a problem with the validation.
I don't get the error Messages shown. And in my calling component i log the changes in the console. But this don't work either.

I think the problem is because of passing of the FormGroup. I get an error in my developer console, which says the formGroup is null. I found old post, which tried to solve this problem. But they are old and i can't fix it with these either.

I would be happy if anybody can help me.

For now i have this in my .html

```
<div class="row justify-content-center py-1">
  <div class="col-sm-2 px-0">
    <label class="col-form-label"><strong>{{ labelString }}</strong></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 px-0">
    <input formControlName="{{ formControlNameString }}" type="text" class="form-control">
    <ng-container *ngIf="formGroup.controls[formControlNameString] as nameString">
      <ng-container *ngIf="nameString.dirty || nameString.touched">
        <ng-container *ngIf="nameString.errors as error">
          <p class="form-error" *ngIf="error?.['required']">
            You need to enter a {{ labelString }}
          </p>
          <p class="form-error" *ngIf="error?.['minlength']">
            You need to enter at least {{ error?.['minlength'].requiredLength }}
          </p>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this in my ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-textfield',
  templateUrl: './textfield.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textfield.component.css']
})
export class TextfieldComponent {

  @Input() labelString: string = '';
  @Input() formControlNameString: string = '';
  @Input() isRequired: boolean = false;
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = fb.group({});
  }
}
```

And i call it like this:

```
<app-textfield
          [labelString]="'Username'"
          [formControlNameString]="'username'"
          [formGroup]="loginFormFB"
        ></app-textfield>
```

I tried a lot of solutions i found on stack overflow. but nothing worked.
Also i always get errors when i try:
`public form: FormGroup`

it says: TS2564: Property 'form' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Comment: Instead of passing `formGroup` as an input, you should try implementing [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) in your component. It's much cleaner, and will save you a lot of trouble. There are multiple guides if you google it, e.g. [this](https://netbasal.com/forwarding-form-controls-to-custom-control-components-in-angular-701e8406cc55)

Comment: ControlValueAccessor might not be exactly a beginner topic, but definitely worth learning on the long run.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I searched for a more specific tutorial. And this is what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

For everybody struggling with this, this is a nice tutorial to work with Control Value Accessors:
[Youtube - TheRyanSmee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTcJQaWiJ2c&ab_channel=TheRyanSmee)
This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).